# Extract Tensor Values using iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

---

I'm trying to extract the values of label for each image of the dataset. My idea is to split train and test :

```
data, info= tfds.load("cats_vs_dogs", as_supervised = True, split = 'train',with_info=True)

# Split into training and test parts
test_dataset = data.take(5500)
train_dataset = data.skip(5500)
```

Then I want to apply **preprocessing** to differentiate according to the label in the training:

```
def preprocess_start(image,label):
  #cast the image values from integers to floating and then divide by 255
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [100, 100])
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)/ 255.0
  if label == 0:   #this check is not correct
    
    code ...
  else:
    code ...
  return image,label

train_test= train_test.map(preprocess_start)
```

However the main problem is that the label is:

```
Tensor("args_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

How can I extract the integer values ?

Comment: Why is that condition not correct ? You mean you have many such conditions ? You code does execute.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I cannot execute the if/else condition in this way

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [AutoGraph Transformations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md)

```
# Split into training and test parts
test_dataset = data.take(5500)
train_dataset = data.skip(5500)

@tf.function
def preprocess_start(image, label):
    # cast the image values from integers to floating and then divide by 255
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [100, 100])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    if tf.equal(label, 0 ):  # this check is not correct
        tf.print("Zero",label)
    else:
        tf.print("Not Zero",label)
    return image, label


train_test = train_dataset.map(preprocess_start)
for e in train_test:
    tf.print(e)
```

So for a simpler function this should work. If you need more complicated logic you have to    read the [rules](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md)

```
Zero 0
Zero 0
Not Zero 1
Zero 0
Zero 0
Zero 0
Not Zero 1
```

So, for example, this check should work as expected.

```
l = tf.constant(0)
if tf.equal(l, 0 ):  # this check is not correct
    tf.print("Zero",l)
else:
    tf.print("Not Zero",l)
```

Comment: It seems to not work, both conditions are right for each label. Why ? I made a small check with just 1 element taken, and it enters both on 0 and 1.

Comment: What is the datarype of label in this case?

Comment: Tensor("args_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)

Comment: I may be missing something. Are you not seeing the output  shown ?

Comment: Tha main problem is that in my case the label is not a tf.constant, if you try to run your code preprocess_start, just for 1 test sample, you will have both print checked

Comment: Even if  you `train_dataset = data.take(1)` I get a proper value depending on whether it is `0` or `1`